# xquery exception [XPTY0019]

Tags: exception, xquery

I am using the following xml file (users_doc.xml)

```
<users>
  <user trusted="false">
    <userid>vsony7@vt.edu</userid>
    <password>sony</password>
  </user>
  <user trusted="false">
    <userid>shivi</userid>
    <password>shivi</password>
  </user>
  <user trusted="false">
    <userid>xyz</userid>
    <password>xyz</password>
  </user>
</users>
```

I am running the following xquery: (Here $doc_name=users_doc, $userid=xyz)

```
declare variable $doc_name as xs:string external;
declare variable $userid as xs:string external;
let $users_doc := doc($doc_name)/users

return delete node $users_doc/user/userid=$userid/..
```

I am trying to find a given node  `<userid>xyz</userid>` and if the user exists I would like to delete its parent node

```
<user trusted="false">
    <userid>xyz</userid>
    <password>xyz</password>
  </user>
```

But, when I run this query I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stopped at line 5, column 51: 
[XPTY0019] Context node required for ..; xs:string found.
```

How do I fix this ?

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#ERRXPTY0019

> **err:XPTY0019**
>
> It is a type error if the result of a step (other than
>   the last step) in a path expression
>   contains an atomic value.

Let's look at your expression:

```
$users_doc/user/userid=$userid/..
```

The left term of the last step is a node set comparison:

```
$users_doc/user/userid=$userid
```

So, it will result in true or false boolean value (an atomic value). Of course, you can't select the `parent::node()` of true or false...

You want this expression:

```
$users_doc/user[userid=$userid]
```